# Segmentation fault in llvm pass when using RegisterStandardPasses

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to run an LLVM pass, but I get segmentation fault. Below is the code for my LLVM pass.

The compiler runs and produces the output. `runOnBasicBlock` works, but afterwards we get this error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

When I remove `RegisterStandardPasses` and `loadPass` (last lines), the code works fine. Any idea what causes this? Thanks

We load the compiler pass using the following line.

```
opt -load ./plugin_build/NvmInstrumenter.so -NvmInstrumenter -stats < simple.bc
```

We use LLVM and Clang version 5.0.0 both downloaded and built at the same time.

The code from the compiler pass:

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/PassRegistry.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"
// For output
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  struct NvmInstrumenter : public BasicBlockPass {
    static char ID;
    NvmInstrumenter() : BasicBlockPass(ID) {}
    virtual bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &BB) {
      BasicBlock::iterator i;
      errs() << "Basic Block\n";
      for( i=BB.begin(); i!=BB.end(); i++ ) {
    errs() << "  " << i->getOpcodeName() << "\n";
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}

// Pass info
char NvmInstrumenter::ID = 0; // LLVM ignores the actual value
static RegisterPass<NvmInstrumenter> X("NvmInstrumenter", "Example pass", false, false);

static void loadPass(const PassManagerBuilder &Builder, legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
  PM.add(new NvmInstrumenter());
}

static RegisterStandardPasses clangtoolLoader_Ox(PassManagerBuilder::EP_OptimizerLast, loadPass);
static RegisterStandardPasses clangtoolLoader_O0(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0, loadPass);
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ff4900 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ff4900 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff58fb4ab in llvm::object_deleter<llvm::SmallVector<std::pair<llvm::PassManagerBuilder::ExtensionPointTy, std::function<void (llvm::PassManagerBuilder const&, llvm::legacy::PassManagerBase&)> >, 8u> >::call(void*) () from /usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/../lib/libLLVM-5.0.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff4cef87d in llvm::ManagedStaticBase::destroy() const () from /usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/../lib/libLLVM-5.0.so.1  
#3  0x00007ffff4cefa15 in llvm::llvm_shutdown() () from /usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/../lib/libLLVM-5.0.so.1
#4  0x00005555555f0ddf in main ()
```

Comment: It works ok here. Can you use `gdb` for more info? Also, if you are not planning to run your pass from `clang`, you can omit that pass registration, especially if it's on level `O0`.

Comment: gdb doesn't give us any useful answer. It just says Segmentation fault. We intend to run it from clang.

Comment: You can use the command `bt` in gdb to obtain a  backtrace (call stack) after it hit the segmentation fault

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. Someone else reported the bug here https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34573 there doesn't seem to be any solution at this point. Did you have any luck fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not alone with this error (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34573), LLVM seems to crash at the end of the program when `RegisterStandardPasses` is used since LLVM 5.

According to this answer: https://github.com/sampsyo/llvm-pass-skeleton/issues/7#issuecomment-401834287 a solution is to add `-Wl,-znodelete` to the compiler flags when you link your program. It worked for me.